# Função para validar xml

Tags: c#, xml

Eu tenho esta função para validar um xml:

```
public static bool ValidarXML(string pathXML, string pathSchema, ref string retorno)
    {
        bool falhou;

        // Define o tipo de validação
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        // Carrega o arquivo de esquema
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        settings.Schemas = schemas;
        // Quando carregar o eschema, especificar o namespace que ele valida
        // e a localização do arquivo 
        schemas.Add(null, pathSchema);
        // Especifica o tratamento de evento para os erros de validacao
        // settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;
        // cria um leitor para validação
        XmlReader validator = XmlReader.Create(pathXML, settings);
        falhou = false;
        try
        {
            // Faz a leitura de todos os dados XML
            while (validator.Read()) { }
        }
        catch (XmlException err)
        {
            // Um erro ocorre se o documento XML inclui caracteres ilegais
            // ou tags que não estão aninhadas corretamente
            retorno = "Ocorreu um erro critico durante a validação do XML: " + err.Message;
            falhou = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            validator.Close();
            retorno = "Arquivo validado com sucesso";
        }
        return !falhou;
    }
```

Porém estou tentando passar o arquivo, e está me retornando erro:

```
 ValidarXML("E:\\nota.xml", typeof(tcNfse), ref a);
```

O schema no caso é o `typeof(tcNfse)`
Ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> não é possível converter de "System.Type" para "string"

Conforme nos comentários, consegui resolver este erro acima adicionando a sugestão:

```
ValidarXML("E:\\nota.xml", nameof(tcNfse), ref a);
```

Porém ele fala que não encontra o `tcNfse`, ele está procurando o arquivo dentro do projeto, no caso eu tenho que passar o local do arquivo, é isso ? em vez dele dentro do programa?

Comment: `(string pathXML, string pathSchema, ref string retorno)` é só olhar a assinatura, onde o segundo parâmetro precisar ser uma `string` !!! entendeu o problema?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu entendi, porém não sei como corrigir, passar o schema como string.

Comment: talvez um `nameOf(tcNfse)` resolva, talvez não sei tente !!! tipo `ValidarXML("E:\\nota.xml", nameOf(tcNfse), ref a);`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu estou tentando passar porém ele diz que não encontra,  Could not find file 'E:\\ERP\\Erp\tcNfse'. o schema está no projeto, o arquivo xsd, tudo certo, será que o certo seria passar o caminho, e não o `tcNfse`?

Comment: Então eu não sei o objetivo do método ... só apontei o problema relatado pela exceção gerada

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vou dar mais uma pesquisada, pra ver se consigo resolver, obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Fiz desta forma: `ValidarXML("E:\\nota.xml", "E:\\xmldsig-core-schema20020212.xsd", ref a);` e consegui resolver. Fica a dica pra quem tiver o mesmo problema.